# Astar XCM Precompile

Tags: astar

I'm running a local node using zombienet, I tried to access to XCM Precompile following [this](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/EVM/precompiles/) guide but when I instantiate the contract and call assets_reserve_transfer method it does not work. I only have access to the first three precompile addresses.
Is it possible to use it or maybe I have to do something else?

I'm running Astar this way:

```
[[parachains]]
id = 2006
chain = "astar-dev"
add_to_genesis = true
cumulus_based = true

  [[parachains.collators]]
  name = "collator1"
  ws_port = 9920
  rpc_port = 8920
  command = "./bin/astar-collator"
  args = [ "-l=xcm=trace", "--enable-evm-rpc" ]
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
 pk,
 provider
);

const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000005004",
   xcmAstarAbi,
   wallet
);

contract.assets_reserve_transfer;
```

I used [this contract](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar-frame/blob/polkadot-v0.9.39/precompiles/xcm/XCM.sol) for the ABI.

Comment: When you say, it does not work, what happens? What version of Astar are you using? Can you link the repo that is causing this issue? Do you also get the issue when you use `shibuya-dev` as the chain? Try using this template for zombienet: https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/third-party/zombienet/multi_parachains.toml

Comment: When I try to do this I get undefined:

const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000005004",
      xcmAstarAbi,
      wallet
    );

console.log(contract.assets_reserve_transfer);


I'm using astar 58
repo: https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar

I also tried with shibuya-dev and shiden-dev but I had the same problem

Comment: Can you try to do the same from Remix?